# get last week start date from current date time in servicenow

Tags: javascript, servicenow

As per my requirement if I pass the date-time then, How I can find which date is present on last week?

E.g.

```
var date1 = new GlideDateTime('2021-10-06 09:00:24');
var date2 = new GlideDateTime('2021-10-12 09:00:37');
```

Output:-

```
date 1 is present on last week.
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this function comparing the numbers of the weeks :

```
function isLastWeek(gdt){
    return gdt.getWeekOfYearLocalTime() === new GlideDateTime().addWeeksLocalTime(-1).getWeekOfYearLocalTime();
}
```